# Brightspace / IMS-LTI content-item message problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, lti

I'm trying to debug posting content via the Content Item Message spec back to Brightspace after a successful launch to my Ruby on Rails application – but I'm getting nothing but inscrutable 500 errors from the Brightspace server –– I presume that I am sending a bad signature (Brightspace confirmed this one time), but I haven't been able to find conclusive documentation on exactly *how* the nonce, timestsamp and signature are calculated, nor have I been able to find an open source library that appears to handle this.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Please  how did you know that the signature is invalid? For me, I'm getting a 200 response with CORS error. When I check in bright space, the only think I see is :"Error validating Content Item Message". Does that mean signature invalid?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that Instructure's [ims-lti gem](https://github.com/instructure/ims-lti), although not documented, can generate signed params which can then be posted server-side or iterated through to render an HTML form client side, and then auto-submit, using the IMS::LTI::Models::Messages::ContentItemSelection class at /lib/ims/lti/models/messages/content_item_selection.rb